# Create Maven Plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, tycho

I would like to create a maven java plugin on top of our EMF model generator (base on eclipse-plugin). Can someone advise me where I should start from? How do I define the dependency as in the model generator, we don't define the dependency one by one.

Thanks

Comment: there is a good guide available at https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html

Comment: Hi @wemu, thanks for the link. I know how to create a maven plugin. But I don't know how to integrate with eclipse plugin.

Comment: Sorry in that case I got your question wrong. I would not try creating both a maven and eclipse plugin at once. Usually plugins are just wrappers for the functionality provided by libraries. So create a library that provides what you need, then the eclipse and / or maven plugin. Depending on what the maven plugin does it might be enough to be run inside eclipse. So I don't really get what you plan to do, so it's hard to say how one could proceed.

Comment: The idea to create maven plugin is to generate EMF model independently from IDE.

Comment: https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-maven ?

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you need the OSGi runtime environment.
If all required bundles are deployed as maven artifacts to a m2 repository you can use them from there, but that's most likely not the case.

Since OSGi and maven use differe t repository types, namely m2 and p2, they are not really good compatible.

I faced a similar problem and our solution was, that we created a eclipse product which holds all the required OSGi bundles and load those in the maven plugin within a newly started OSGi container.

We found no solution to the combination of p2 and m2 repositories to resolve dependencies efficient.